# Moving program created with QT to fresh system

Tags: linux, qt

I have created simple widget based GUI application in my CentOS 32 bit Linux. Now I'm trying to move binary to another fresh CentOS 32 system that has no QT installed.

Got error

`:error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I was trying to fix that by installing qt libs:

`sudo yum install qt-devel`

But still got the same error

Comment: **Off-topic** here. It is a sysadmin issue (how to install Qt on the other system). You may want to install the Qt runtime library (not only the development version) and you might need to restart the system. [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask (but  search by  yourself the web before asking). You could also make a genuine [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) for your application (with dependencies). Or you could recompile your app on the target system

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am confused why consider _deployment_ issues as _off-topic_

Comment: Because OP don't show any [MCVE] and  probably could not show any. StackOverflow is about programming (not deployment) issues.

Comment: [Qt for Linux - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html)